# Why do we use RESTful Api's

Tags: database, api

Recently I came to know about RESTful API's.
The problem or point here is that I found it similar to databases.

So instead of using API's can we use database and its query?

If No, What's the reason?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rest API incases connects to databases and and queries the output. You need Rest API because they are fast along with other benefits. The Front end or your other systems cannot understand database and its language so you need an intermediate in between (like a common ground) to help two systems talk to each other. Largely this was SOAP Services with XML couple of yrs back and now its Rest API with JSON.

Rest API is the glue between your trasnaction system (database) and the front end system in your case.

Comment: Most of this answer is complete gibberish.

Comment: First of all, "You need Rest API because they are fast" – speed is not an issue, of course a direct connection to a database would be faster than going through an intermediary system. Secondly, "The Front end or your other systems cannot understand database and its language" – there is no technical reason why you couldn't pass raw database queries to the backend, it would just be a really, really bad idea. The main point of an API is to *restrict* direct access to the database so that the user can't just pass `DROP TABLE users;` or fetch data that they're not allowed to see...

Comment: ...or just DOS the system by passing convoluted queries. Only the last paragraph of the answer is (mostly) correct, the explanation is not.